# Raspberry pi not executing files

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os

I am using a Raspberry Pi4. When clicking on an executable (not .exe) file, it says to execute or execute in terminal. If I click either option, it seems like it's opening, then it immediately closes. I have tried to fix this problem, but I am yet to find something relevant.

Comment: how do you know that the file is not executed?

Comment: nothing opens when I click either option

Comment: i apologize for my wording. the files I have in my downloads folder, which are executable, give me two options to execute with terminal or just execute. i talked about the specific file incase there are other ways to add them

Comment: it is still not clear what is the problem that you are perceiving ... you are decribing normal behavior for some executables ... please  add a description of what you expect to happen when you click on the exacutable